# usermod -a -G group user not work

Tags: permissions, group

I use Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to add the user `gefalko` to the `www-data` group. I use

```
root@xxx~# usermod -a -G www-data gefalko
```

If I understand correctly, I should now see `www-data` in the output of `groups` when run by gefalko:

```
gefalko@xxx:~$ groups
```

However, there is no www-data in the output:

```
gefalko adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

I want to edit `index.php` owned by www-data, but I can't (permission denied):

```
gefalko@xxx:/var/www/html/projectx$ ls -l
total 1320
...
-rwxrwxr-x  1 www-data www-data    1613 Bal 18 10:18 index.php
...
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When changing a user's groups, the changes don't take effect until the next time the user logs in. So, you can either log out and log back in again or start a new login shell as gefalko:

```
$ groups
sys lp wheel optical scanner terdon
terdon@oregano ~ $ sudo usermod -a -G www-data terdon
terdon@oregano ~ $ groups
sys lp wheel optical scanner terdon   ## no change

$ su terdon -   ## start a new login shell
Password: 
$ groups
sys lp wheel optical scanner terdon
```

Comment: In my case, it wasn't just logging out. I had to RESTART. Just in case it helps others! +1